# Set path for non shell user

Tags: centos, path, java

I have installed Adopt OpenJDK version of Java. I set it up so all users will have `JAVA_HOME` set and that the bin folder for Java is in the `PATH`. However the software I installed afterwards that requires Java creates a non shell user and runs as that user. Since the user is non shell it does not get the environment variables I set in `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`. Is there a way to append to the path for any user whether they have a shell or not? I can't find any information on this since when I search all answers just talk about creating the bash script in `/etc/profile.d`. I am using CentOS 7.5.